# access rights depending on mount

Tags: shell

I cannot access a directory and I don't understand why:

The user 'exchange' is in the right group and can access on non mounted dir application1_exchange_test but not application1_exchange. The only difference is that application1_exchange is a nfs mount.

```
root@application2-dev:/var/spool/application1_exchange/from# namei -mo `pwd`
f: /var/spool/application1_exchange/from
 drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
 drwxr-xr-x root    root    var
 drwxr-xr-x root    root    spool
 drwxrwx--- tomcat8 tomcat8 application1_exchange
 drwxrwxr-x tomcat8 tomcat8 from

root@application2-dev:/var/spool/application1_exchange/from# su exchange

exchange@application2-dev:/var/spool/application1_exchange/from$ groups 
exchange tomcat8

exchange@application2-dev:/var/spool/application1_exchange/from$ ls -ld . .. ../..
ls: cannot access '../..': Permission denied
drwxrwxr-x  3 tomcat8 tomcat8 4096 Jun 21 07:31 .
drwxrwx--- 11 tomcat8 tomcat8 4096 Jun 21 07:31 ..

exchange@application2-dev:/var/spool/application1_exchange/from$ cd /var/spool/application1_exchange
bash: cd: /var/spool/application1_exchange: Permission denied

exchange@application2-dev:/var/spool/application1_exchange/from$ cd /var/spool/

exchange@application2-dev:/var/spool$ ls -dl application1_exchange*
drwxrwx--- 11 tomcat8 tomcat8 4096 Jun 21 07:31 application1_exchange
drwxrwx---  3 tomcat8 tomcat8 4096 Jul  9 11:08 application1_exchange_test

exchange@application2-dev:/var/spool$ ls -l application1_exchange*
ls: cannot open directory 'application1_exchange': Permission denied
application1_exchange_test:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat8 tomcat8 4096 Jul  9 11:08 from

exchange@application2-dev:/var/spool$ findmnt /var/spool/application1_exchange
TARGET                       SOURCE                     FSTYPE OPTIONS
/var/spool/application1_exchange 192.168.1.1:/mnt/exchange nfs    rw,relatime,sync,vers=3,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,
```

The ownership of the unmounted dir doesn't play any role. It was root but also with tomcat8 it the same.
The nfsd / export options are  rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check

Comment: The issue will most probably be to do with the nfs root_squash option that is implemented by default. I would suggest that you take a look at the man pages for "exports"

Comment: Can you unmount that filesystem and check the output of `ls -dl application1_exchange` ? On some operating systems, the permissions on the underlying mount point matter.